# How do I split a string, convert to double, and output a string again? Java! (Code not working)

Tags: java

I am a beginner java coder on an assignment. Please don't report as too vague/duplicate etc, I really need help tailored to me as I have looked at many other answers and just dont understand whats going on!

This bit of code is where my string - e.g. 5x^3 + 2x^2 will be input

```js
    String P = Polynomial; 
    Expression poly = new Variable(P); 
    Expression diffpoly = poly.derive();
```

Here is my code where I need the help:

```js
public class Variable implements Expression 
{
    private double coeff1, power1,newcoeff,newpow;
    private String stringpoly; 
    
//public Variable(String[] t) 
    public Variable(String p)
      {
        stringpoly = p; 
      }
    public Expression derive() 
      {
      String[] parts;
      parts = stringpoly.split("x");
      coeff1 = double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
      power1 = double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
      newcoeff = coeff*power1;
      newpower = power1-1; 
      String newcoeffstr = Double.toString(newcoeff);
      String newpowerstr = Double.toString(newpower);
      String differentiatedterm = newcoeffstr + "x^" + newpowerstr; 
      return new Variable(differentiatedterm);
      }
    public double evaluate(double a) 
      {
        return stringpoly;
      }
    public String toString() 
      {
        return Double.toString(stringpoly);
}
}
```

So my issue, is that I am getting errors saying

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7OPj.jpg)
Can anyone explain these errors for me?

Comment: You should remove the javascript tag.

Comment: You put `java` in your title and in your first sentence, then tag it as `javascript`. Nice.

Comment: Wrong approach in the first place: you should really learn to create a **parser** here. Assuming that you just split around `x` is way too naive. You need a *parser* that translates your expression into a **tree** of nodes. The whole point of such exercises is to add more and more features over time. Which will cost you more and more time if you stay with this naive approach. Thus: learn about parsers, and how to build them (and hint: it is not that hard)

Comment: And unrelated: A) dont tell people to not downvote for "too broad input" - avoid creating downvote-worthy input instead B) improve the naming in your code (by learning about java naming conventions and by using meaningful names ` a`  means **nothing**, and `newcoeffstr`  could be something `newCoefficient` )

Comment: There is a difference between `double` and `Double` in Java. `double` is a primitive type and has no method `parseDouble`. Please check for `Double.parseDouble(String s)`

Comment: Read language spec, read examples, use an IDE, use a debugger. Only then come and ask! Downvote

Answer (score 0):

`double` is a primitive datatype in java. It does not represent an object or a class.
To call methods an object or at least a class is required.

Check the documentations for primitive types [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
Check the different wrapper classes and how to use them [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/wrapper-class-in-java)

You will have to use the `double`'s wrapper class `Double` to be able to call the function `parseDouble(...)`

```
double parsedNumber = Double.parseDouble("1083407810329");
```